# continuity of the function $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{x}{(kx+1)[(k+1)x+1]}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, sequence-of-function

I need to check the continuity and differentiability of the function $f(x)$ at $x=0$ where, $$f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{x}{(kx+1)[(k+1)x+1]}.$$

I tried to check the domain of convergence convergence, and applied the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), but the ratio is coming one and hence unable to conclude anything. If the function converges uniformly the also we can say the limit will be continuous but I am unable to check the convergence. How will I check the continuity and differentiability of this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Write the numerator as

$$(k+1)x+1-(kx+1)=?$$ to form a telescoping series

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks.