# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{[(n-1)x+1](nx+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

> Consider,
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{[(n-1)x+1](nx+1)}$$
>
> defined on $[0,1]$
>
> Does this series converge point-wise and uniformly to a function on $[0,1]$?

How can I approach this problem? Since I have nothing to show for effort, I request you to give me some hints.

Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172254/continuity-of-the-function-fx-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-0n-1-dfracxk

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Should I delete the question?

Comment: You should if you think its duplicate

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Does the series converge pointwise to $1/(x+1)$? And the series is not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$